# Determining what the meaning of part of a character '益' is

Tags: glyph-origin

I can see that it have an equal number of strokes above and below the yi stroke not part of the blood radical.  I am not sure of what this character is..I mean..I know 高兴, that is the closest that I know.

If you would like read at where this question a rose from, you are invited for a reading.  haha.

恰合

叶 部 让 拟 囡 过  烨 补 让 袮 囝 过 也 不 让 倪 难 国。
伙 的 保 护 神 真 格 潨 聚 合 和 合 力 合 合 理 威 容 故 亦 变 奕 闻 达 的 问 答。
圈 圏 变 変 合 圆 也。
尔 过。
翼 加 医 家 一 家 怡。

Comment: 益 radical：皿，dish，top, bottom both have 5 strokes, 血 itself is a radical, according to 小马词典 there are 3 characters, 血衅衄 with radical 血

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outlier** gives the following definition:

> **FORM**
>
> 益 depicts a bowl (皿) with water ([image]) flowing out of it, representing the original meaning “abundant, more than enough.”

With a reference to page 147 of:

> 裘錫圭，1991《文字學概要(再版)》，臺北市：萬卷樓，2006年2月再版8刷。

It then continues:

> **COMPONENTS**
>
> [image]
>
> In 益, [image]  “flowing water” is a form component.
>
> 皿
>
> In 益, 皿 “bowl” is a form component.

Original forms looked something like:

[image]

It goes to show that the entire thing was originally the *meaning* part.

Comment: Basically, the top 益 is 水 written sideways. I'd also recommend @AbeShudug to see this: http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%9B%8A - useful website to check for glyph origins. Their explanation given on the oracle bone character is: **甲骨文「益」從「皿」從「水」，會器皿中水滿而溢出之意。本義是溢出，是「溢」的初文，引申為増益、利益。**, which matches the Outlier definition exactly.